# How to create an opt-out link for each cookie we use on our site?

Tags: cookie, gdpr

Under the new GDPR directives, we should provide ways to remove / block cookies that our sites send to the user's browsers upon user's request.

How to do it? Is there some HTML/javascipt solution to selectively remove the cookies?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you asking from a usability or implementation perspective? But either way, this seems too broad a question? "Is there some HTML/javascipt solution..." - what if you are setting cookies with your server-side code? What about 3rd-party cookies?

Comment: I'm talking about the implementation of some tool to allow/disallow cookies being set, clicking on an Accept or Decline Cookies button. Here I found some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306254/is-it-possible-to-block-cookies-from-being-set-using-javascript-or-php

Comment: And even better would be having some customized optout links on the Cookies Policy page, to fine tune what people accepts and what not. Something like this, but applied to any cookie, not just Analytics: https://webgilde.com/en/analytics-opt-out/

Comment: I think the article at `webglide.com` is out of date. With regards to the new GDPR ruling, the overall logic is reversed. The user must now explicitly _opt-in_, not be implicitly opted-in, with an option to opt-out (as it used to be). By default, the user is implicitly _opted-out_.